# number of ordered submultisets in A000707

Tags: combinatorics

$A000707$ gives the number of unordered multisets.  What is the number of ordered multisets?  Beginning with $1,2,2,3,3,3,4,4,4,4$ the sequence for $n_1 \to n_4$ begins $1,3,19,175$. Thus for $n=3 (1,2,2), (1,3,3) (2,2,3), (2,3,3)$ each have three arrangements; $(1,2,3)$ has six arrangements; and $(3,3,3)$ has one, giving a total of $4\cdot 3+6+1=19$.

Answer (score 3):

This is the labeled species for $n$ fixed

$$\mathfrak{P_{\le 1}}(\mathcal{Z})
\mathfrak{P_{\le 2}}(\mathcal{Z})
\mathfrak{P_{\le 3}}(\mathcal{Z})
\cdots
\mathfrak{P_{\le n}}(\mathcal{Z}).$$

This represents a  row of $m$ available ordered slots  where we select
at most one to contain the value one, at most two to contain the value
two, at most three to contain the  value three and so on and the slots
per value form a set. This yields the exponential generating function

$$G(z) = \prod_{q=1}^n \left(\sum_{p=0}^q \frac{z^p}{p!}\right).$$

We are interested in $n! [z^n] G(z)$ or

$$n! [z^n] \prod_{q=1}^n \left(\sum_{p=0}^q \frac{z^p}{p!}\right).$$

Implemented like this:

```
Z :=
proc(n)
option remember;
local gf;

    gf := mul(add(z^p/p!, p=0..q), q=1..n);
    n!*coeff(expand(gf), z, n);
end;
```

it yields the sequence

$$1, 3, 19, 175, 2111, 31321, 550810, 11194177,\ldots$$

which points  us to  [OEIS A129481](http://oeis.org/A129481)  where we
discover that apparently not much else is known about these numbers.

Comment: The OEIS entry does suggest that for large $n$ this is close to $0.66$ times the number $n$ element ordered submultisets there would have been if the original multiset had had $n$ copies of each of the first $n$ numbers